# Why does svelte handle "value" differently from other attributes?

Tags: svelte, svelte-native

In svelte (3.42.5) attributes named "value" are translated differently from other attributes.

I.e. the component

```html
<progress value="50" max="100"/>
```

translates to

```js
...
function create_fragment(ctx) {
    ...
    return {
        c() {
            progress = element("progress");
            progress.value = "50";
            attr(progress, "max", "100");
        },
        ...
```

As one can see the attribute "value" is set in another way than "max". Although this is perfectly correct javascript code in browser it makes [svelte-native struggle](https://github.com/halfnelson/svelte-native-preprocessor/issues/15).

Furthermore I ask myself why svelte has this special handling?!? And is there a way to turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `value` is a reserved keyword to set the *value* of this tag/component.

For example: when you are using select & option tags, the value of the option is set with the *value* key word.

```
<select bind:value={selected}>
    <option value={a}>a</option>
    <option value={b}>b</option>
    <option value={c}>c</option>
</select>
```

So I would say no, you can not deactivate this behavior.

Reference: https://svelte.dev/docs#Binding_select_value